# Second dual of a Grothendieck space

Tags: banach-spaces

The classical example of a Grothendieck space is $\ell_\infty$. It is also known that its even duals $\ell_\infty^{**}$, $\ell_\infty^{****}$, $\dots$ are Grothendieck spaces.

(See, e.g., [this paper](http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-18-3/18J3Plich.pdf) for the proof of Grothendieck property of these even duals. Their proof uses the fact that these spaces are C(K) spaces for large Stonian K-s.)

My question is:
Is it known, in general, if the second dual of a Grothendieck space is 
a Grothendieck space too? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: the [same question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/149326/second-duals-of-grothendieck-spaces) on MO